# Сломан пакет linux-firmware (Pop OS 20.04)

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg

При попытке обновиться `apt update && apt upgrade` терминал выдаёт следующее:

```
Настраивается пакет linux-firmware (1.187.1+system76~1594927000~20.04~854aab7) …
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-7634-generic
E: busybox or busybox-static, version 1:1.22.0-17~ or later, is required but not
 installed
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-7634-generic with 1.
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 linux-firmware
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Информация о системе:

```
             /////////////                george@pop-os 
         /////////////////////            ------------- 
      ///////*767////////////////         OS: Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS x86_64 
    //////7676767676*//////////////       Host: Aspire A315-41G V1.11 
   /////76767//7676767//////////////      Kernel: 5.4.0-7626-generic 
  /////767676///*76767///////////////     Uptime: 2 hours, 38 mins 
 ///////767676///76767.///7676*///////    Packages: 2259 (dpkg) 
/////////767676//76767///767676////////   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
//////////76767676767////76767/////////   Resolution: 1920x1080 
///////////76767676//////7676//////////   DE: GNOME 
////////////,7676,///////767///////////   WM: Mutter 
/////////////*7676///////76////////////   WM Theme: Pop 
///////////////7676////////////////////   Theme: Pop-dark [GTK2/3] 
 ///////////////7676///767////////////    Icons: Pop [GTK2/3] 
  //////////////////////'////////////     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   //////.7676767676767676767,//////      CPU: AMD Ryzen 3 2200U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (4) 
    /////767676767676767676767/////       GPU: AMD ATI Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M4 
      ///////////////////////////         GPU: AMD ATI Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile S 
         /////////////////////            Memory: 3852MiB / 4899MiB 
             /////////////
```

Вывод `apt install -f`

```
root@pop-os:~# apt install -f
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 159 пакетов не обновлено.
Установлено или удалено не до конца 1 пакетов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 0 B.
Настраивается пакет linux-firmware (1.187.1+system76~1594927000~20.04~854aab7) …
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-7634-generic
E: busybox or busybox-static, version 1:1.22.0-17~ or later, is required but not installed
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-7634-generic with 1.
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 linux-firmware
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

busybox-static установлен, версия как требуется:

```
root@pop-os:~# dpkg -s busybox-static
Package: busybox-static
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: shells
Installed-Size: 2224
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: busybox
Version: 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.1
Replaces: busybox
Provides: busybox
Conflicts: busybox
Description: Standalone rescue shell with tons of builtin utilities
 BusyBox combines tiny versions of many common UNIX utilities into a single
 small executable. It provides minimalist replacements for the most common
 utilities you would usually find on your desktop system (i.e., ls, cp, mv,
 mount, tar, etc.).  The utilities in BusyBox generally have fewer options than
 their full-featured GNU cousins; however, the options that are included
 provide the expected functionality and behave very much like their GNU
 counterparts.
 .
 busybox-static provides you with a statically linked simple stand alone shell
 that provides all the utilities available in BusyBox. This package is
 intended to be used as a rescue shell, in the event that you screw up your
 system. Invoke "busybox sh" and you have a standalone shell ready to save
 your system from certain destruction. Invoke "busybox", and it will list the
 available builtin commands.
Built-Using: glibc (= 2.31-0ubuntu9)
Homepage: http://www.busybox.net
Original-Maintainer: Debian Install System Team <debian-boot@lists.debian.org>
```

При попытке переустановить linux-firmware:

```
root@pop-os:~# apt reinstall linux-firmware
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Переустановка linux-firmware невозможна: он не может быть загружен.
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 44 пакетов не обновлено.
Установлено или удалено не до конца 1 пакетов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 0 B.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] Д
Настраивается пакет linux-firmware (1.187.1+system76~1594927000~20.04~854aab7) …
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-7634-generic
E: busybox or busybox-static, version 1:1.22.0-17~ or later, is required but not installed
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-7634-generic with 1.
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 linux-firmware
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

sources.list

```
  GNU nano 4.9.3                          /etc/apt/sources.list                                   
# deb cdrom:[Pop_OS 20.04 _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200514)]/ focal main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary focal main
deb-src http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary focal main
#deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
#deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

dpkg --configure -a

```
root@pop-os:~# dpkg --configure -a
Настраивается пакет linux-firmware (1.187.1+system76~1594927000~20.04~854aab7) …
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-7634-generic
E: busybox or busybox-static, version 1:1.22.0-17~ or later, is required but not installed
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-7634-generic with 1.
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 linux-firmware
```

Comment: Тут нужна отладка. В дебиан (и убунту, и popos) принято для успешной установки, необходимо, чтобы скрипт в post installation секции deb пакета успешно отработал. Соответственно, у Вас происходит именно так. Скрипт не отработал, dpkg вернул ошибку, все сломалось. Что делать? Посмотреть глазами, что там внутри это скрипта - это не сложно. Любой deb пакет имеет четко регламентированную структуру. И легко может быть разобран на части. Либо, емнип, есть опция запуска dpkg с дополнительной отладочной информацией - это может помочь получить больше данных для анализа.

Comment: скрипты лежат в каталоге `/var/lib/dpkg/info`. имя файла начинается с имени пакета. post-installation скрипт имеет суффикс `.postinst`. таким образом просматривать надо скрипт `/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-firmware.postinst`

Comment: впрочем, post-installation скрипт пакета linux-firmware содержит всего лишь запуск `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs -u -k all`. так что проблема в содержимом скрипта `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs` и того, что в нём запускается. удачи!